# Problem with validates_uniqueness_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, authlogic

I'm using rails 2.3.5 and Authlogic in our website, and I have been getting errors on the database through hoptoad of users with duplicated emails trying to be saved. The problem is, obviously I have the `validates_uniqueness_of :email` on the model.

On my tests here in development I get the expected validation error and the user is not saved, but in production, I keep getting this errors on the DB layer.

I've tested with case sensitive emails and it also validated correctly.

I've checked and the class and there is no attr_accessor or any other attribute override, and I don't think Authlogic would do it in a wrong way...

What could be happening in production? Are there any cases where rails validates doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Locate the SQL running `validates_uniqueness_of` in your development log, and if you see something like `WHERE (email = BINARY 'foo@example.com')`, try creating a user with `FOO@EXAMPLE.COM` and now you can reproduce the DB-level duplicate exception.

To fix this, put the following code in `config/initializers/patches.rb`:

```
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter
  def case_sensitive_equality_operator
    "="
  end
end
```

Note that `Mysql2Adapter` should be `MysqlAdapter` if you're on Rails 2.

On a side note, it is a longstanding bug in Rails IMO - handling case-sensitivity in Ruby level doesn't make sense at all. If you need case-sensitive lookup, you should have the column collation of `utf8_bin`. If you need case-insensitive lookup, you should have the column collation of `utf8_general_ci`. Applying `BINARY` function in the where clause will disable the use of index, and `validates_uniqueness_of` causes full table scan every time you try to create/update a record. If you have millions of records, you're totally screwed. The patch above will fix that, too - in fact, it was my original motivation to create that patch.

If you agree, please +1 to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1399 :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried recreating the scenario. Why should throw errors that warrant Hoptoad Notification. I mean, basically if you have a it should not save the user and not throw an error for hoptoad to notify you about.

Also with authlogic, i don't think you are required to specify the validate_uniqueness_of for email. Usually authlogic will take care of that for you.

So I guess, its time for you to deep dive.

Look at the logs, and try recreating this error locally. Its always best to retrace the steps leading to error.

More details, error stack , code would definitely be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I know hoptoad shouldn't throw errors when an email is already existent. It should simply validate and go back to the form with the message "This email is already in use". That behaviour is happenning in almost all cases, but on few cases rails is validating an email that already exists, so it tries to save the user, and the database throws the error because of the UNIQUE index. I am trying to recreate it, but I get the correct behaviour instead of the error, even with the same data :/

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but could it be that your email column allows null, validates_uniqueness_of is ignoring nil (or blank) values and that your users are trying to register without specifying their email addresses?

Comment: No, the errors are always with emails being passed but already in the database. I also validate presence of email, so I don't think rails is failing at 2 validations at once

Comment: So much for that idea then. I suggest changing your production app's error logging level so it shows the queries it's running. I suppose it could be a case sensitivity issue too or perhaps related to trailing spaces?